# nodejs executing external function from script

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I installed nodejs and jsdom on my linux server.

I am trying to do something that should be simple but I cannot find any easy tutorials online for this.

I am simply trying to run a the function "randomtest()" from an external .js file (http://yourjavascript.com/64473118216/nodejstest.js)

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var test = require("./libs/nodejstest.js");

jsdom.env({
    html: "<div></div>",
    done : function (error, window) {
        test.randomtest();
    }
});
```

It produces following error:
[image]

I have also tried loading it via the "scripts" tag for jsdom like this to no avail:

scripts : ["http://yourjavascript.com/64473118216/nodejstest.js"],

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env({
    html: "<div></div>",
    scripts: ["./libs/nodejstest.js"],
    done : function (error, window) {
        window.randomtest();
    }
});
```

Comment: randomtest does return the value but the "console.log" inside it does not execute (or at least does not print anything in my putty window). if i do - var test = window.randomtest(); console.log(test); - that prints the result though

Comment: Probably it happens because console is not correctly defined inside your client-side function. You can handle it by passing window object into your function (if you realy need). So you should write `window.randomtest(window);` and correct your function like: `function randomtest(wnd){window = wnd || window; var a=1.6;var b=8.77;var c=a*b; window.console.log('calc: '+c);return c;}`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with what you tried:

1. Loading your `nodejstest.js` through Node's `require` does not work make the `randomtest` function available because **`nodejstest.js` does not export anything.** It would have to export `randomtest` with something like `exports.randomtest = randomtest`.
2. You said using `scripts : ["http://yourjavascript.com/64473118216/nodejstest.js"],` in the configuration does not work, but in fact it does. You do not see the output on the console because **the window that JSDOM creates is essentially a new JavaScript virtual environment, and it has its own `console` separate from Node's `console`.** You have to create a bridge between the two, like this:

   ```
   var jsdom = require("jsdom");

   var vc = jsdom.createVirtualConsole();
   vc.on("log", function () {
       console.log.apply(console.log, arguments);
   });

   vc.on("jsdomError", function (er) {
       throw er;
   });


   jsdom.env({
       html: "<div></div>",
       scripts : ["http://yourjavascript.com/64473118216/nodejstest.js"],
       virtualConsole: vc,
       done : function (error, window) {
           window.randomtest();
       }
   });
   ```

   With this, the output will show on your console.